# How can I take the crystal skull without candles?

Tags: zork

I accidentally left the candles burning in the altar and went to do other stuff, by the time I returned, the candles were too short to even light. But the candles are needed to take the crystal skull, so how do I restore the candles please?

Comment: Old adventure games (and they don't get much older than Zork) often give you every chance to render them Unwinnable.  Perhaps this is one of those times.